# Linking two tables with nothing in common

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to join these statements:

```
select min(len(Password)) as min, 
       max(len(Password)) as max, 
       avg(len(Password)) as avg 
FROM Customer.dbo.Password 

UNION ALL
select min(len(password2)) as min, 
       max(len(password2)) as max, 
       avg(len(password2)) as avg 
FROM website.dbo.password2
```

To these:

```
SELECT c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'website' db FROM website.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN website.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U'

UNION
SELECT c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'Customer' db FROM Customer.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN Customer.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U'
```

They have no columns in common. The first two SELECT statements produce three columns of the min, max and avg of password length and second two produce colName, tableName and db name of where the password is held.

I'd like to display both result sets in one table purely for visual reasons, to get the corresponding the min, max, avg to the appropriate colName, tableName and db.

I tried doing it this way:

```
DECLARE @numberTable TABLE (link nvarchar(500), max int, min int, avg int)
INSERT INTO @numberTable

select 'link', min(len(Password)) as min, 
       max(len(Password)) as max, 
       avg(len(Password)) as avg 
FROM Customer.dbo.Password UNION ALL
select 'link', min(len(password2)) as min, 
       max(len(password2)) as max, 
       avg(len(password2)) as avg 
FROM website.dbo.password2

SELECT * FROM @numberTable ORDER BY max

DECLARE @myTable TABLE (link nvarchar(500), colName nvarchar(500), tableName   nvarchar(500), db nvarchar(500))
INSERT INTO @myTable

SELECT 'link', c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'website' db FROM website.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN website.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U' UNION

SELECT 'link', c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'Customer' db FROM Customer.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN Customer.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U' 

SELECT * FROM @myTable ORDER BY db

SELECT link
FROM @myTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN @numberTable
ON @myTable.link = @numberTable.link
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Hope what I'm after makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross join` to join two unrelated tables:

```
SELECT  c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName
,       o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName
,       'website' db 
,       pwd.[min]
,       pwd.[max]
,       pwd.[avg]
FROM    website.sys.all_columns as c 
INNER JOIN 
        website.sys.all_objects o 
ON      c.object_id = o.object_id 
CROSS JOIN
        (
        select min(len(Password)) as min, 
               max(len(Password)) as max, 
               avg(len(Password)) as avg 
        FROM   website.dbo.Password        
        ) as pwd
WHERE   c.name like '%password%' 
        AND type = 'U' 

UNION

SELECT  c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName
,       o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName
,       'Customer' db 
,       pwd.[min]
,       pwd.[max]
,       pwd.[avg]
FROM    Customer.sys.all_columns as c 
INNER JOIN 
        Customer.sys.all_objects o 
ON      c.object_id = o.object_id 
CROSS JOIN
        (
        select min(len(Password)) as min, 
               max(len(Password)) as max, 
               avg(len(Password)) as avg 
        FROM    Customer.dbo.Password        
        ) as pwd
WHERE   c.name like '%password%' 
        AND type = 'U'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create something arbitrary that they do have in common and join them

```
Select * 
from
(
select 
       1 as RowID,
       min(len(Password)) as min,  
       max(len(Password)) as max,  
       avg(len(Password)) as avg  
FROM Customer.dbo.Password  

UNION ALL 
select 
       2,
       min(len(password2)) as min,  
       max(len(password2)) as max,  
       avg(len(password2)) as avg  
FROM website.dbo.password2 
) t1
inner join
(


SELECT 1 as RowID, c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'website' db FROM website.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN website.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U' 

UNION 
SELECT 2, c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 'Customer' db FROM Customer.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN Customer.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like '%password%' AND type = 'U' 
) t2
    on t1.rowID = t2.rowID
```